# I don't want to define models twice in any of Node ORM lib's

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have an MySQL database with couple tables and I started to use Node ORM lib's like Sequelize.

Every ORM tutorial have an article about model definition like:

- http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/
- https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/wiki/Defining-Models

So... Really? Can ORM generate model automatically, please? Kohana ORM and Idiorm doesn't want me to define model by myself.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto

Comment: So I should regenerate model after any changes in DB structure?

Comment: yes you have to regenerate after every change when using https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto